# Trying to replace the text E with scientific notation

Tags: import, replacement

How to replace the E with scientific notation `*^`?

```
{0.1971468 E - 001, 0.1422880 E - 001, 0.2046836 E - 001, 
      0.1394519 E - 001, -0.9795244 E - 002, 0.1424443 E - 001} /. E -> *^
```

Comment: Where does this data come from? That's certainly not Mathematica syntax for expressing scientific notation. Did it come as a string?

Comment: it's a TextPad data imported into Mathematica

Comment: `StringReplace["{0.1971468 E-001,0.1422880 E-001,0.2046836 \
E-001,0.1394519 E-001,-0.9795244 E-002,0.1424443 E-001}", "E" -> "*^"]`

Comment: How'd you import it? Copy paste?

Comment: No `Import["modesshapes_evolution.txt", "Text"];`

Comment: Rather than post-processing the imported text, I’d focus on finding an import method that takes care of the conversion to start with.

Comment: See below: have you tried `Import["modesshapes_evolution.txt", "CSV"]`?

Comment: I'd say "How to replace E?" is the wrong question. The right question would be: how to import that data? It's hard to tell without seeing your datafile, but most likely `Import[..., "Table"]`.

Comment: Please amend the question and show the datafile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = Import["modeshapes_evolution.txt", "Lines"];
b = StringSplit[a, ","];
c = StringReplace[#, "E - " -> "*10^-"] &  /@ b;
data = ToExpression[c]
```

The above works on a text file with lines that contain your sample data.

**Better method:**

To use MMA's built-in data format conversion, as suggested by @Roman, you could simply remove the spaces and read the text as data:

```
s = Import["modeshapes_evolution.txt", "String"];
data = ImportString[StringReplace[s, " " -> ""], "Data"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The input as a string (maybe read from a file):

```
S = "{0.1971468 E - 001, 0.1422880 E - 001, 0.2046836 E - 001,
      0.1394519 E - 001, -0.9795244 E - 002, 0.1424443 E - 001}";
```

Delete whitespace and curly braces, then import as CSV:

```
ImportString[StringDelete[S, "{" | "}" | " " | "\n"], "CSV"]
(*    {{0.0197147, 0.0142288, 0.0204684, 0.0139452, -0.00979524, 0.0142444}}    *)
```

From [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html): "Import automatically recognizes common number formats, including C and Fortran notations."

Maybe it's enough to import your entire file as `CSV` instead of as `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica 12 both do not work

(i) direct input of the given list,

(ii) first enter = and then the list

because all suppress or ignore the E.

Just in the expansion of the link "Show all solution" the E is identified.

The solution is the step suggested by Xminer after entering the = for the Wolfram Alpha type of input interpretation and 10 instead of *. The trick is not to enter

```
StringReplace["{0.1971468 E-001,0.1422880 E-001,0.2046836 \ E-001,0.1394519 E-001,-0.9795244 E-002,0.1424443 E-001}","E"->" 10^"]
```

direct in the = line, but to copy and paste the output[image]